# Data is not ready when retrieving session parameter from the server using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm building an application using [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel). I have a controller which returns a session parameter from the server.

I'm retrieving this parameter using an [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) request from a view blade as follow:

```
var url = CMS_URL + 'GetSystemMode/';
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'text',
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("data: " + data);
  }
});
```

The code running on the server side is:

```
Route::get('/GetSystemMode', function () {
   return Session::get('systemMode');
});
```

In localhost, I'm getting the right `"data"` and the code works as a charm, but in production, `"data"` is always empty.

It's like the success method is executed before the data is yet retrieved from the server side.

This issue took to much time from me, and I don't have any idea how to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: `In production, I'm getting the right "data" and the code works as a charm, but in production, "data" is always empty.` ... wait what?

Comment: Did you tried to use $.ajax.done()?

Comment: Can we see the full code?

Comment: @Twinfriends I meant in localhost, thanks for pointing that out for me.

Comment: @AlexAndre actually yes, I've tried using done, but still the same result.

Comment: @SupunFictionPraneeth I just added the code running on the server side. Is any thing else needed? Thanks.

Comment: Okay since its a get method, can yiu validate the url ? So go to the console and check whether it's going to the correct url

Comment: the only thing i can think of where did u put ur ajax call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our production environment was at the appEngine, so due to the server restirctions, it wasn't allowed to save the sessions on files as was done on localhost. So the problem was actually that the server is not saving the sessions at all and therefor I'm getting empty data.
I solved it by installing redis and saving the sessions over it.